# Plink does not work with commands file for git in sudo

Tags: ssh, git, sudo, plink

I use plink.exe for automatisation of git commands and this works fine. But i need to use this with servers with login of sudo

```
plink.exe -ssh argentium@186.118.154.164 -m commands.txt
```

my commands.txt file for example:

```
echo -e "MYPASSWORD\n" | sudo -S -i
cd /home/www/argentium.ru
git checkout HEAD~3
```

and output looks like loged in, but git executes as if it works without login of sudo:

```
[sudo] password for argentium: fatal: Unable to create '/home/www/argentium.ru/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

With help putty.exe works fine

```
сentos-7-x86_64-minimal @ 23.11.2016
-bash-4.2$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for argentium:
[root@stilnoeserebro ~]# cd /home/www/argentium.ru
[root@stilnoeserebro argentium.ru]# git checkout HEAD~3
Note: checking out 'HEAD~3'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `sudo -S -i` reads the password and commands from standard input.

In `echo -e "MYPASSWORD\n" | sudo -S -i` standard input is from the pipe, which returns a new-line, then end-of-file after the password is read: the remaining commands are run in the normal shell.

There are a couple of ways round: what is closest to what you have coded is to use a *here-document*:-

```
sudo -S -i <<EOF
MYPASSWORD
cd /home/www/argentium.ru
git checkout HEAD~3
EOF
```

Alternatively, you can add all the commands to the input stream:-

```
echo -e "MYPASSWORD\ncd /home/www/argentium.ru\ngit checkout HEAD~3" | sudo -S -i
```

Note that I have tested this on a normal `bash` shell, as I don't have a set-up where I can easily test with `plink`.

Comment: The alternative variant is look obviously. I could have guessed... Now i understand the sense.
But the first variant is convenient. Thank you very much!